# Passing an object from one module into a subroutine of another module

Tags: oop, object, fortran, gfortran

I have two module files mod1.f95 and mod2.f95. Mod1 has mathematical functions such as rk4 and interpolation methods, and I have been trying to keep it general so that I can reuse the module for other projects. Mod2 has a class structure defined within it, Obj1, and is meant to be specific to this project. The issue is that a subroutine defined in mod1 now needs an object definition passed something along the lines as

```
subroutine driver(x1, x2, func, this)
  real(kind=8) :: x1, x2
  external :: func, this         ! this is the Object
  ! ...
end subroutine driver
```

The error I get from this is

```
Type mismatch in argument 'this' at (1); passed TYPE(Obj1) to UNKOWN
```

I had a feeling this would happen, since the `external` keyword is meant for functions and subroutines, but I would like to pass an Object to the subroutine without having to hard code my mod2 into mod1 (i.e. using `use mod2`)

I tired this change

```
subroutine driver(x1, x2, func, this)
  real(kind=8) :: x1, x2
  class(Object) :: this
  external :: func
  ! ...
end subroutine driver
```

but got `Derived type 'object' at (1) is being used before it is defined`.
I also tried `type(Object) :: this` with the same error produced.

To reiterate, I would like to see if there is a way to initialize an Object in a "general" sense so that other modules and files I create can just be linked this mod1 without having to change the code inside. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you against (the correct) `use mod2`?  If you want to have an accessible definition of `object` then you haven't many alternatives.  If you can explain what you want to do with `this` we may be able to suggest things.

Comment: If `mod1` is supposed to be generic how has it come about that an object defined in another module 'needs' to be passed into `mod1` ?  I spy a defect in analysis.  Could you not write a routine in `mod2` (where the object is defined) which calls the routine from `mod1` on specific members of the object ?

Comment: In the subroutine the `external :: func` also happens to be part of the Class object in this sense, so it would look something like `call func(this,x1,x2)`. I guess I was thinking how in other languages classes inherit from an overarching Object Class, because the subroutine driver doesn't actually do anything with the object besides passing it to `func`

Comment: Is the goal to pass a function of some specified interface (say, for Runge-Kutta) that uses Obj1 (or some variables depending on mod1) as internal data?